# How to iterate through list of maps in terraform while creating locals?

Tags: terraform

I have a variable like below

```
subnets = [
{      
      app_name = "app1" 
      subnets = {
       "us-west-1a" = ["10.85.1.128/26", "10.85.1.192/26", "10.85.2.128/26", "10.85.2.192/26", "10.85.3.64/26", "10.85.3.128/26", "10.85.3.192/26", "10.85.4.0/26", "10.85.4.64/26", "10.85.4.128/26", "10.85.4.192/26", "10.85.5.0/26", "10.85.5.64/26", "10.85.5.128/26", "10.85.6.64/26", "10.85.6.128/26", "10.85.6.192/26"]
       "us-west-1b" = ["10.85.1.128/26", "10.85.1.192/26", "10.85.2.128/26", "10.85.2.192/26", "10.85.3.64/26", "10.85.3.128/26", "10.85.3.192/26", "10.85.4.0/26", "10.85.4.64/26", "10.85.4.128/26", "10.85.4.192/26", "10.85.5.0/26", "10.85.5.64/26", "10.85.5.128/26", "10.85.6.64/26", "10.85.6.128/26", "10.85.6.192/26"]
       "us-west-1c" = ["10.85.1.128/26", "10.85.1.192/26", "10.85.2.128/26", "10.85.2.192/26", "10.85.3.64/26", "10.85.3.128/26", "10.85.3.192/26", "10.85.4.0/26", "10.85.4.64/26", "10.85.4.128/26", "10.85.4.192/26", "10.85.5.0/26", "10.85.5.64/26", "10.85.5.128/26", "10.85.6.64/26", "10.85.6.128/26", "10.85.6.192/26"]
      }
},

     {
      app_name = "app2"
      subnets = {
       "us-west-1a" = ["10.85.1.128/26", "10.85.1.192/26", "10.85.2.128/26", "10.85.2.192/26", "10.85.3.64/26", "10.85.3.128/26", "10.85.3.192/26", "10.85.4.0/26", "10.85.4.64/26", "10.85.4.128/26", "10.85.4.192/26", "10.85.5.0/26", "10.85.5.64/26", "10.85.5.128/26", "10.85.6.64/26", "10.85.6.128/26", "10.85.6.192/26"]
       "us-west-1b" = ["10.86.1.128/26", "10.86.1.192/26", "10.86.2.128/26", "10.86.2.192/26", "10.86.3.64/26", "10.86.3.128/26", "10.86.3.192/26", "10.86.4.0/26", "10.86.4.64/26", "10.86.4.128/26", "10.86.4.192/26", "10.86.5.0/26", "10.86.5.64/26", "10.86.5.128/26", "10.86.6.64/26", "10.86.6.128/26", "10.86.6.192/26"]
      }
    }
  ]
```

I want to create a local which should give value as below

```
{app_name = app1
 cidr_block = "10.85.1.128/26"
 az = us-west-1a}
{app_name = app1
 cidr_block = "10.85.1.192/26"
 az = us-west-1a}
.............
{app_name = app2
 cidr_block = "10.85.1.128/26"
 az = us-west-1a}
{app_name = app2
     cidr_block = "10.86.1.128/26"
     az = us-west-1b}
```

I tried like below.But i'm not able to split the list and do 1 more iteration

```
locals {
int_subnets = toset(flatten([
for app in var.subnets: [
 for az,cidr in app.subnets : {
 app_name = app.app_name
 cidr_block = cidr
 az = az
 }
 ]]))

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for s in local.int_subnets : "${s.app_name} ${s.cidr_block}" => s
  }

  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr_block
  availability_zone = each.value.az

  tags = {
    Name = "${each.value.app_name}-Int-${split("-", each.value.az)[2]}"
  }
}
     }
```

Getting below error

```
on main.tf line 49, in resource "aws_subnet" "example":
│   49:     for s in local.int_subnets : "${s.app_name} ${s.cidr_block}" => s
│     ├────────────────
│     │ s.cidr_block is tuple with 17 elements
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Please let me know is it possible to do 1 more iteration and split the cidr block list into string or do we have any other better approch for the same

Comment: Your example of "a local which should give value as below" is not fully clear. Do you want to have first CIDR for all each AZ or all of them? i.e. your example has different values in app1 and in app2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may want to have something like this:

```
locals {
  int_subnets = toset(flatten([
    for app in var.subnets : [
      for az in keys(app.subnets) : [
        for subnet in flatten(app.subnets[az]) : [
          { "app_name" : app.app_name,
            "az" : az,
            "cidr_block " : subnet
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]))
}
```

This will produce an output in this format:

```
int_subnet = ([
  {
    "app_name" = "app1"
    "az" = "us-west-1a"
    "cidr_block " = "10.85.1.128/26"
  },
  {
    "app_name" = "app1"
    "az" = "us-west-1a"
    "cidr_block " = "10.85.1.192/26"
  },
...
  {
    "app_name" = "app2"
    "az" = "us-west-1a"
    "cidr_block " = "10.85.1.128/26"
  },
  {
    "app_name" = "app2"
    "az" = "us-west-1a"
    "cidr_block " = "10.85.1.192/26"
  },
...
```